# Ninject: Injecting two different objects of same type

Tags: c#, ninject

If I have a class, which has dual dependencies on the same type (needs two different instances), if the only difference between the instances is a deeper dependency, what's the best way to have Ninject perform DI and keep the two graphs separate?

**Example object graph:**

```
foo → ClassA → ClassB
bar → ClassA → ClassB
```

**Class `C`'s constructor:**

```
public class C
{
    public C(ClassB foo, ClassB bar) { … }
}
```

So how do I make sure that the `ClassB` instantiated with `foo` gets supplied as the `ClassB` dependancy `foo`, and `bar`… `bar`?

Just for some background, I had some requirements change, so I need to replace a write-only repository (IAdd) with a composite write-only repository

```
public class CompositeWriteRepository<T> : IAdd<T>
{
    public CompositeWriteRepository(IAdd<T> foo, IAdd<T> bar, Func<T, bool> descriminator) { ... }
    public Add(T entity)
    {
        if (descriminator(entity)) {
            foo.Add(entity);
        } else {
            bar.Add(entity);
        }
    }        
}
```

With mocking, that was easy enough, I could just inject using names:

```
 kernel.Bind<IAdd<EntityType>>().To<fooRepository>().Named("foo");
 kernel.Bind<IAdd<EntityType>>().To<barRepository>().Named("bar");

 kernel.Bind<IAdd<EntityType>>().To<CompositeWriterRepository<EntityType>>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("foo", x => x.Kernel.Get<IAdd<EntityType>>("foo")
    .WithConstructorArgument("bar", x => x.Kernel.Get<IAdd<EntityType>>("bar");
```

The problem comes when I use the real repositories; `foo` and `bar` ultimately write to files so they need different file names.  Since they're `StreamWriter` repositories, one of their dependencies actually gets the two different file names.

```
string FileName → FileStreamWriterFactory → StreamRepository → CompositeRepository
```

The only way I've found thus far to construct things is to make a named `FileName`, named `FileStreamWriterFactory`, named `StreamRepository` × 2 (once for `foo` and once for `bar`). This seems like *a lot* of work, so I hope there's a better solution.

I can re-architect if needed, it felt like an elegant way to quickly add in seperating the entries when the requirements changed. I realize my classes all are quite specific, but I think single responsibility would support this generally and in my case we write a bunch of small applications and have more requests the we can fulfill so its a good way to have lot's of re-usable code laying around that I basically just need to re-configure for different tasks.

**Solution**
Remo Gloor should get credit; his is probably the best practice.

What I actually did was create a new extension

```
public static bool WhenAnchester(this IRequest request, Func<IRequest, bool> conditions)
{
    var parentContext = request.ParentContext;
    if (parentContext == null) {
            return false;
    }

    return conditions(parentContext.Request) || 
        parentContext.Request.WhenAnchester(conditions);
}
```

This then let me easily control which file get injected into which repository.

```
kernel.Bind<string>().ToConstant("Foo.txt")
    .When(x => x.Target.Name == "filepath" && 
              x.WhenAnchester(t => t.Target != null && t.Target.Name == "Dest1"));

kernel.Bind<string>().ToConstant("Bar.txt")
    .When(x => x.Target.Name == "filepath" &&
               x.WhenAnchester(t => t.Target != null && t.Target.Name == "Dest2"));
```

There's probably a better solution, so I wouldn't necessary recommend this for others, but its working well for me.

Comment: DI containers are supposed to un-tie the dependencies from particular implementations, so the classes rely only on interfaces. And you want the opposite, the thing we try to avoid following IoC ideas.

Comment: I'm swapping out one implementation of IAdd for another and I did so only be writing one new class (the composite IAdd) and by changing my composition root. Granted, its not a very strong indication I'm using DI correctly, but that doesn't seem like a code sniff to me.  The complication is actually because my class don't care, so I end up with two VERY similar dependency graphs and my composition does need to care (and should) because the business requirements make it so. I could introduce a two new types to differentiate, it might be cleaner, but its also more changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a better way

See https://github.com/ninject/ninject/commit/60443badf4ef840531c93e9287b154a9bba337c2

It's 3.0 but IsAnyAnchestorNamed can also be used with 2.2 from a When condition.