# What causes the Ninject.Activation.IRequest Target property to be null

Tags: ninject, ninject-3, contextual-binding

Probably a simple question, but I did not find anything in the documentation or on SO that directly answers it.

I had to work with the Ninject `When(Func<IRequest, bool> condition)` extension method for the first time, and got hung up for a bit with null object exceptions.  I figured out that the `IRequest.Target` property is sometimes null and I've seen some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404389/ninject-injecting-two-different-objects-of-same-type) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606848/ninject-how-to-dynamically-select-an-implementation-to-bind-to-an-interface/4607274#4607274) using `When` that check for a null `Target` as well.

I'm curious about the conditions under which Ninject executes the callback without having a value for `Target`.  When creating a binding of the form

```
Bind<T1>()
   .To<T2>
   .When(r => SomeTest(r.Target));
```

I initially and erroneously assumed that there would always be a valid `Target` of type `T1` when the binding was being executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is null for the root object because there is no target in this case. (`kernel.Get<MyCompositionRoot>()`)

Comment: So does this mean that if a type `T1` is *only* present as a constructor argument, then `Target` will not be null?  To put it another way, if I encounter a null target, does that necessarily mean that there is some bit code somewhere requesting the binding directly, e.g. `var x = kernel.Get<T1>()`?